# Eclipse Git - move project to another local Git repository

Tags: eclipse, git

I use Eclipse Oxygen and Git on Windows.

I have just added my new maven project to a wrong Local Git Repository (that contains other projects !).

How can I move it to the rigth one ? Or how can I remove it from the wrong local repository and after, add it to the right one ?

I have read that we can copy the directory with .git file to the right repository but I don't want to affect the others projects !!

Comment: Have you already committed or even pushed your local changes into the wrong repository?

Comment: hi @howlger, no

Comment: Then delete the project in Eclipse without deleting its content, move the project to the correct Git repository directory and in Eclipse, in the _Git Repositories_ view right-click and choose _Import Projects..._.